# Find page url for image

Tags: 2013, search, content-type, search-api

**Creating an image gallery.**

If a user clicks on a thumbnail the bigger image is loaded into a modal and they can pinch/zoom to see detail. If the title of the image is clicked it'll take them to the page where the image resides. This information is being pulled in using the search API from the custom content type.

The content type has all the information I need but the page URL the image resides on. Is there a way of using REST API to retrieve this URL?

Here's the initial search api:

```
_api/search/query?querytext=%27ContentType:Custom_AssetImage%27&selectproperties=%27OriginalPath%2c+SiteName%2c+PictureThumbnailURL%2c+Title%2c+Keywords%27&clienttype=%27ContentSearchRegular%27
```